# UITableViewCell strange background resizing in editing mode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

Here is my customized `UITableViewCell` with background image etc. When I call `[tableView setEditingMode:YES];` - editing controlls scale my background image and it looks very bad. See screenshots:

[image: Vertical]

[image: Full description]

Cell background scales when edit controlls appear. How to fix this? I've tried to manipulate with `UIAutoresizingMask`, but no results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have better results if you add your background image directly on the UITableViewCell's view instead of its contentView. The view of that UITableViewCell is not in any way resized when switching to editing mode.

Comment: Thank you. I made this step simpler - just connected that UIImageView to cell's background property in Interface Builder. Now it's not resizing. Thanks!:)

Answer (score 0):

Dude, there's another way !

just add this inside your cell:

[self.contentView setAutoresizesSubviews:NO];

Best regards